# How to check if a type is abstract in .NET Core?

Tags: reflection, types, abstract-class, .net-core, coreclr

This code works fine in .NET (4.6 and prior)

```
var types = typeof(SomeType).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetTypes()
from type in types
where !type.IsAbstract
```

but in .NET Core (DNX Core 5.0) it is producing a compile error:

> Error CS1061  'Type' does not contain a definition for 'IsAbstract' and no extension method 'IsAbstract' accepting a first argument of type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So **how can I check if a type is abstract in DNX Core 5.0** the way I do it in .NET Framework 4.6?

[image]

Comment: `type.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Exactly what I am looking for! Add it as an answer.

Comment: That wouldn't be a very good answer TBH, and I expect this to be a duplicate

Comment: I think it would be good to add this as an answer (even a self answer), just to make it easier for people to see. Particularly as this post has quite a few votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting one of the comments as an answer since it is what I was asking for:

```
type.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract
```