# How to parse a JSON object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit

I have a method which is returning Json Result Like :

```
return Json(new { status = "error", message = "The organization cannot be deleted because contains transmitters!" });
```

Now I want to test with status and Message I have tried with this

```
var result = Controller.DeleteOrganization(2) as JsonResult;
Assert.AreEqual("error", result.Data.message);
```

I am getting **Error:**

> object does not contain a definition for message

How can I resolve this Issue?

Comment: the Data is of type `object` and would not be exposing the property. Try assigning the Data property to a `dynamic` variable and then try accessing the property. if that does not work then I gave an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38446754/5233410) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38552771/5233410) that you can adapt to your problem.

Comment: yes, you are right. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Data` is of type `object` and would not be exposing the property. Try assigning the Data property to a `dynamic` variable and then try accessing the property.

```
var result = Controller.DeleteOrganization(2) as JsonResult;
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Data);
var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(data);
Assert.AreEqual("error", deserializedData.status);
```

If that does not work then I gave an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38446754/5233410) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38552771/5233410) that you can adapt to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use json2csharp.com convert JSON to C#
2. Create a class file put the code
3. Add the Newtonsoft.Json library to your project using the Nuget Package Manager
4. Convert the JSON

   RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

Comment: Thanks for your Reply But, I have tried with 
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var jsonResult =serializer.Deserialize<Result>(result.Data.ToString()); as well

Comment: JavascriptSerializer is deprecated, please use NewtonSoft Json for better performance and other reasons.